# How can I allow owner of document in Library to manage permission on that document?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

When a user uploads a document, I need them to be able to manage permissions on that particular document, but only have Contributor access to other documents.  Ideas on how to do that?  If there is a patch already out there, that would be nice.

My Ideas

1. Write a feature that hooks the upload or check-in event, then gives Created By user full control.

Answer (score 1):

I support your idea you can write a Item event reciever and on itemadded event make the creator of the document as the owner of the document you might have to use spelevated privalages to provide him the same permissions

Answer (score 1):

To save you having to start writing event handlers etc... have you checked out the Custom Workflow Activities on CodePlex here: http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/ as one of the activities deals with giving permissions to the item the workflow is running on.

Hope this helps.